# Remove space in list

Tags: html, css

Guys u i have some space in `ul` list. I try to set `padding: 0` and `margin: 0` and not work i has again space near left border.
Check my screenshot:

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```css
div.topbar-list > ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
}
div.topbar-list > ul > li {
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
div.topbar-list > ul > li:first-child {
  border-right: 0 none;
}
div.topbar-list > ul > li a {
  color: #333;
}
div.topbar-list > ul li:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
div.topbar-list > ul > li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar-list">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i>  +381 123 342 543</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-mobile-phone"></i> +381 123 432 542</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-mobile-phone"></i> +381 315 645 122</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also i try to debug it from `Inspector/Firebug` but there is not any padding and fixed width.
How i can remove that white space?

Answer (score 3):

```
Use Float:left; instead of display:inline-block;
```

Because display:inline-block always put some spacing.

Comment: Yeah work perfect. Thanks @Mukesh Ram

Answer (score -1):

that's caused by the "display: inline-block". To fix it you can give the element a negative margin.

Comment: You are correct about the `inline-block`, though negative margin won't fix it.

Comment: Chris, are you sure? I've used the negative margin in one of my project and it worked perfectly...

Comment: It's more of a hack, than a proper fix really. The initial space is still there. It's better to just remove the space altogether.

Comment: Negative margins will work but is a bad way to do this. The reason is because the space depends on various factors like the font, its size etc. So a `margin-right: -4px` would not work for all cases.